# Interacting with low level device from VB

Tags: vb.net, assembly, embedded

A friend of mine wants to write a VB application that interacts with an embedded device. Here's a basic outline of the system -

A user puts a coin into a slot (as with any arcade machine or vending machine).

This then triggers the VB application to run.

That is as much as I know about this application, it has nothing to do with me i was just asked about how it would work. I told him you coin machine would fire off a signal when a coin is inserted and he would listen for these using sockets or open pipes to the embedded device...I presume that is how this would work yes?

I also told him that the coin machine isnt as straightforward as he thinks as you need to account for all use cases...you are not just 'listening for a coin insert', you have to handle situations like coin value, another coin being input while the system is already running, etc...

- So how would the coin machine and the VB application interact...pipes/sockets?
- Is it possible to buy devices like this coin machine somewhere?
- Is it straightforward making such a device interact with VB? Ie. would there be libraries for this kind of thing or would you need to custom write both the code for the device itself and the VB code for listening for signal from it?

Comment: In order for this question to be answerable, you have to tell us what hardware interfaces the embedded device supports.

Comment: I dont know. I was asked about this by a guy who knows nothing about embedded devices, he knows a bit of VB thats it. I've done a good bit of pc assembly language but I know very little about embedded devices.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how the device connects, but you need a driver in between the application and the lower-level IO to the device.

The easiest way to do a button press or two would be to use a standard USB-to-Serial converter.  You can get these for about $1 online.  RS232 ports have status lines for things like "ring indicator" and such.  When the switch shorts the right pins, you can detect the serial port status in your application.  This is a cheap way to do what you want.

[image: RS232 Pinout]

If you need something a bit more advanced, dig into USB HID.  You can easily [program with HID devices from .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18099/A-USB-HID-Component-for-C).

Comment: That assumes that the coin op hardware has a serial interface, which it may or may not.

Comment: @EricJ., No, it doesn't assume this at all.  Please re-read my answer.  I don't suggest actually communicating over the data pins... I'm simply talking about controlling the status lines.  See also:  http://old.nabble.com/Serial-port-switch-td15996615.html  It's easy enough to hook up any coin switch to the status lines, and monitor them.  No extra hardware or real communication needed.

Comment: So would the coin machine already come pre coded and ready to fire the signals from coin inputs? If it comes precoded, is the driver you are talking about a C based wrapper that takes the signals being output and sends to sockets/pipes? So that VB can pick them up?

Comment: And is it possible to actually buy one of these devices or do they only come built in to full systems such as a vending machine?

Comment: @Jim_CS, No, if you are buying a coin machine with a PC interface, it will dictate how the communication works.  (Probably HID, but not always!)  I am suggesting you connect the output pins of your coin machine up to a relay to signal your computer over a serial port... AKA, making your own generic PC interface.  And yes, if you wanted to buy one, they do exist.

Comment: @EricJ. On the other hand, UART peripherals are so utterly common on microcontrollers, that it is quite a task to find one lacking it.

Comment: @Jim_CS For RS-232 communication you need no Windows driver, simply use the existing Windows API functions directly from VB. VB even has a serial port component, which is more limited than the raw API, but might be sufficient to get the job done. Forget about sockets and pipes.